# Hide status bar but not custom UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow, ios7-statusbar

I have a custom UIWindow that is my own status bar, so I want to hide the status bar and show mine instead. I have

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

In both my UIWindow's rootViewController and the main ViewController. This hides the status bar, but it also hides my UIWindow. My UIWindow's `windowLevel` is `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1`, but I tested other `windowLevel`s and it was hidden regardless of the level.

Setting an opaque background for my custom UIWindow is not an option.

How can I hide the status bar but not my custom UIWindow?

Comment: is it an option for you to hide it only in specific view controllers?

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic, I can either hide on all or specific ones: It doesn't matter

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic, might it be a problem with the Simulator? I can't test on my device now.

Comment: I guess you will only find out when you try it :(

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic, I just tried it, and it does not work on a device either :( Any ideas? Is it possible to see what the system does when it reads `prefersStatusBarHidden` on the code level?

Comment: *"and show mine instead."*
Not sure App Review team will like this bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: better solution

The same still holds true as before/below, but the actual code is shorter, simpler, and more Swifty.

In your AppDelegate, have

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    myStatusBarWindow.isHidden = false
    return true
}
```

And, of course, hide the system status bar. Either do this in the build settings or info.plist, or in your view controller, say

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Much better :)

---

**Old solution**

Unfortunately, I cannot find what is probably the best answer, but I have a workaround:

First show your window. Only after that should you hide the status bar. I am not sure *why* this works, but it does. You can do that like this:

```
// Class var 
var statusBarHidden = false

// For example in viewDidLoad but only the order matters
override func viewDidLoad() {
    myWindow.isHidden = false
    statusBarHidden = true
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

Through my experimentation I discovered that `prefersStatusBarHidden` is checked *before* `viewDidLoad`. Thus, we need to tell the view controller to check again once the window is shown. Again, I don't know why this works, but it does. If anyone can explain this phenomenon (why this order matters), that would be an excellent supplement to this solution.